# jQuery - selector can't be found, while they exist

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following function in jQuery:

```
WeeklySchedule.prototype.FillSchedule = function(jsonData)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.ScheduleItems.length; i++)
    {
        var item = jsonData.ScheduleItems[i];
        var itemId = item['TimeScheduleItem']['id'];
        var date = item['TimeScheduleItem']['date'];
        var employerId = item['Employer']['id'];
        var profilePhoto = item['Employer']['profile_photo'];

        $('.day .day-indicator#' + date).siblings('.day-schedule').append('<div class="roster-item left" id="' + itemId + '"></div>');
        $('.roster-item#' + itemId).append('<img class="profile-photo" id="' + employerId + '" alt="" src="/img/' + profilePhoto + '">');
    }

    $('.day-schedule').append('<div class="clear"></div>');
}
```

Basically, this function searches the correct day and adds a photo to that day. Adding the *"roster-item"* container is working fine. But finding the same container with the *"itemId"* is not working at all.

Using *"$('.roster-item#' + itemId)"* should return the just created div, but it can't find that div, while it exists in html.

**Part of HTML after adding the div:**

```
<div id="3" class="day left ui-droppable">
    <div id="2014-09-25" class="day-indicator today">Thu 25</div>
    <div class="day-schedule">
        <div id="3" class="roster-item left"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding any extra selectors like *".day"* also doesn't work, same as putting it outside the loop. It just can't find it.
I am completely puzzled by why jQuery cant find it.

Comment: This maybe unrelated to the problem you're facing but you should change your `HTML` generation logic to have unique `IDs`.

Comment: Seemed like I indeed needed unique id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `id` for any element in html then it should be unique through out the document. And no need to use any other selector with `id`, so change below code

```
$('.day .day-indicator#' + date).siblings('.day-schedule').append('<div class="roster-item left" id="' + itemId + '"></div>');
$('.roster-item#' + itemId).append('<img class="profile-photo" id="' + employerId + '" alt="" src="/img/' + profilePhoto + '">');
```

to

```
$('#' + date).siblings('.day-schedule').append('<div class="roster-item left" id="' + itemId + '"></div>');
$('#' + itemId).append('<img class="profile-photo" id="' + employerId + '" alt="" src="/img/' + profilePhoto + '">');
```

And if you still want to use `id` selector with `class` selectore then put id in first place then class

```
$('#' + date+'.day .day-indicator').siblings('.day-schedule').append('<div class="roster-item left" id="' + itemId + '"></div>');
$('#' + itemId+'.roster-item').append('<img class="profile-photo" id="' + employerId + '" alt="" src="/img/' + profilePhoto + '">');
```

Comment: It was indeed based on not having unique id's. Never had trouble with it before though. Thanks

Comment: yeah, `id` must be unique always whenever using jquery.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, not only for `jQuery`, all elements SHOULD have unique `IDs` irrespective of the library used.

Comment: @jSang, yeah I agree with you. It is good practice to have unique IDs which will save your time in debugging such issues and outcome is always clean.